# Why is Future in this test never completing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was testing a service I wrote which returns a `Future`, but this weird behavior happened when I awaited the result of the future and the test never completed. Trying to reproduce the error in a minimal way, I got this:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('...',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    print('awaiting');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // never completes
    print('done'); // not reached
  });
}
```

but this completes normally:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('...',
      () async {
    print('awaiting');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // completes normally
    print('done'); // prints "done"
  });
}
```

why is the first one not completing, what am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50783 this may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `tester.runAsync` solves the problem (I still don't know why I need to run my function within this function). It is used like this as per [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50783#issuecomment-614222492) github issue:

```
await tester.runAsync(() async {
     // run my function here
 });
```

Comment: `testWidgets` runs its callback in a [`fake_async`](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_async) `Zone` so that asynchronous code can be tested *deterministically*.  In the example from your question, instead of using `tester.runAsync`, you could do `tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 2));` to advance the `fake_async` clock by 2 seconds and to fire scheduled timer events. `runAsync` might be necessary for other cases though.

Comment: @jamesdlin  I know what you are talking about, I faced it when I started doing widget tests. However, this never occurred to me before (as far as I can remember) with any async code other than pumping a widget. And also see VladyslavUlianytskyi answer below, he is saying it worked with him. What is the reason in your opinion?

Comment: VladyslavUlianytskyi ran the test on a device/emulator, which uses `LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding` instead of `AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding`.  The latter uses `fake_async`.